# How to remove duplicated entries?

Tags: python, arrays

```
Input: new_mainArr[] = 

['the', 'at', 2]
['fulton', 'np-tl', 1]
['county', 'nn-tl', 1]
['grand', 'jj-tl', 1]
['jury', 'nn-tl', 1]
['said', 'vbd', 2]
['friday', 'nr', 1]
['an', 'at', 1]
['investigation', 'nn', 1]
['of', 'in', 1]
["atlanta's", 'np$', 1]
['recent', 'jj', 1]
['primary', 'nn', 1]
['election', 'nn', 1]
['produced', 'vbd', 1]
['.', '.', 2]
['the', 'nn', 1]
['jury', 'nn', 1]
['further', 'rbr', 1]
['in', 'in', 1]
['term-end', 'nn', 1]
['presentments', 'nns', 1]
['that', 'cs', 1]
['city', 'nn-tl', 1]
```

I want to collect same 0'th index elements in one row to remove dupplicates. As you see, there are 2 'the' and 'jury' elements. I want to bring their next elements to the same
and delete the 2nd 'the' and 'jury' rows.
I wrote below code but 2nd 'the' and 'jury' rows still stays. Where should I edit my code?

```
# add duplicate tags for the same word

resultArr = []
temp = []

for i in range(0, len(new_mainArr)):
    temp = []
    temp.append(new_mainArr[i][0])
    temp.append(new_mainArr[i][1])
    temp.append(new_mainArr[i][2])
    hook = new_mainArr[i][0]

    for j in range(i+1, len(new_mainArr)):
        if(new_mainArr[j][0] == hook):
            temp.append(new_mainArr[j][1])
            temp.append(new_mainArr[j][2])
    resultArr.append(temp)
```

Output:

---word with different tags---

```
['the', 'at', 2, 'nn', 1]
['fulton', 'np-tl', 1]
['county', 'nn-tl', 1]
['grand', 'jj-tl', 1]
['jury', 'nn-tl', 1, 'nn', 1]
['said', 'vbd', 2]
['friday', 'nr', 1]
['an', 'at', 1]
['investigation', 'nn', 1]
['of', 'in', 1]
["atlanta's", 'np$', 1]
['recent', 'jj', 1]
['primary', 'nn', 1]
['election', 'nn', 1]
['produced', 'vbd', 1]
['.', '.', 2]
['the', 'nn', 1]  <= this one should not be in the output
['jury', 'nn', 1] <= this one should not be in the output
['further', 'rbr', 1]
['in', 'in', 1]
['term-end', 'nn', 1]
['presentments', 'nns', 1]
['that', 'cs', 1]
['city', 'nn-tl', 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the input list and check whether the first element is already exists. Let me know if I misunderstand your problem.

```
resultArr = []
processed_words = set()

for i in range(len(new_mainArr)):
    word = new_mainArr[i][0]
    if word in processed_words:
        continue

    temp = new_mainArr[i].copy()
    processed_words.add(word)

    for j in range(i + 1, len(new_mainArr)):
        if new_mainArr[j][0] == word:
            temp.extend(new_mainArr[j][1:])

    resultArr.append(temp)

print("---word with different tags---")
for entry in resultArr:
    print(entry)
```

Output:

---word with different tags---

```
['the', 'at', 2, 'nn', 1]
['fulton', 'np-tl', 1]
['county', 'nn-tl', 1]
['grand', 'jj-tl', 1]
['jury', 'nn-tl', 1, 'nn', 1]
['said', 'vbd', 2]
['friday', 'nr', 1]
['an', 'at', 1]
['investigation', 'nn', 1]
['of', 'in', 1]
["atlanta's", 'np$', 1]
['recent', 'jj', 1]
['primary', 'nn', 1]
['election', 'nn', 1]
['produced', 'vbd', 1]
['.', '.', 2]
['further', 'rbr', 1]
['in', 'in', 1]
['term-end', 'nn', 1]
['presentments', 'nns', 1]
['that', 'cs', 1]
['city', 'nn-tl', 1]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a really elegant solution.

Comment: Functionally correct but remarkably inefficient

Comment: This is O(n^2), while this can be done in linear time...

Answer (score 1):

Just use a dictionary to keep track of duplicates like this:

```
data = [
    ["the", "at", 2],
    ["fulton", "np-tl", 1],
    ["county", "nn-tl", 1],
    ["grand", "jj-tl", 1],
    ["jury", "nn-tl", 1],
    ["said", "vbd", 2],
    ["friday", "nr", 1],
    ["an", "at", 1],
    ["investigation", "nn", 1],
    ["of", "in", 1],
    ["atlanta's", "np$", 1],
    ["recent", "jj", 1],
    ["primary", "nn", 1],
    ["election", "nn", 1],
    ["produced", "vbd", 1],
    [".", ".", 2],
    ["the", "nn", 1],
    ["jury", "nn", 1],
    ["further", "rbr", 1],
    ["in", "in", 1],
    ["term-end", "nn", 1],
    ["presentments", "nns", 1],
    ["that", "cs", 1],
    ["city", "nn-tl", 1],
]

d = dict()

for e, *r in data:
    d.setdefault(e, []).extend(r)

output = [[k, *v] for k, v in d.items()]

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[['the', 'at', 2, 'nn', 1], ['fulton', 'np-tl', 1], ['county', 'nn-tl', 1], ['grand', 'jj-tl', 1], ['jury', 'nn-tl', 1, 'nn', 1], ['said', 'vbd', 2], ['friday', 'nr', 1], ['an', 'at', 1], ['investigation', 'nn', 1], ['of', 'in', 1], ["atlanta's", 'np$', 1], ['recent', 'jj', 1], ['primary', 'nn', 1], ['election', 'nn', 1], ['produced', 'vbd', 1], ['.', '.', 2], ['further', 'rbr', 1], ['in', 'in', 1], ['term-end', 'nn', 1], ['presentments', 'nns', 1], ['that', 'cs', 1], ['city', 'nn-tl', 1]]
```

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Oops. I completely misread the question. Now corrected